# How to modify the given Code to open two links in one click (None of the solutions worked for me)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wanted to modify  code to open two links in one click . I searched on Internet and on StackOverflow too but none of these worked for me !

Need Help

Thanks

CODE :

```
function display()
    {
        $('.btn-free').hide();
        $('.download-timer').show();
        if (seconds == 0)
        {
            $('.download-timer').html("<a href='<?php echo validation::safeOutputToScreen($file->getNextDownloadPageLink()); ?>'><?php echo pluginHelper::pluginEnabled('mediaplayer') ? t("download_view_now", "download/view now") : t("download_now", "download now"); ?></a>");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.download-timer-seconds').html(seconds);
        }
        seconds--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People may find this very annoying

```
   function openTwoWindows() {
       var one = window.open("http://example.com/pageone.html");
       var two = window.open("http://example.com/pagetwo.html");
   }

   $("#go-button").on("click",openTwoWindows);
```